# MyApp.App does not contain a definition for Initialize after adding ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, resourcedictionary

Everything is fine till I add a resource dictionary. Then it looks like:

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.MyApp.Common">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:MainMenuButtonVisibilityConverter x:Key="MainMenuButtonVisibilityConverter" />  <!-- withoot this line is fine-->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

App.g.cs:

```
namespace MyApp {
...
    public static void Main() {
        MyApp.App app = new MyApp.App();
        app.InitializeComponent(); // <------ here is the problem
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

MainMenuButtonVisibilityConverter:

```
namespace MyApp.MyApp.Common
{
public class MainMenuButtonVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
...
}}
```

My error:

```
Error   2   'MyApp.MyApp.App' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'MyApp.MyApp.App' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My project name: MyApp
Folder with ViewModels and Common also is caled: MyApp

What am I doing incorrectly while adding resource dictionary?

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyApp.MyApp
{
public partial class App : Application
{
    private Shell shell;
    private MyAppMain myAppMain;

    public App()
    {
    }

    private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Hand);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        base.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(this.Dispatcher_UnhandledException);
        myAppMain = new MyAppMain("");
    }

}}
```

Comment: What does your code behind for `MyApp.App` look like?

Comment: What do mean "code behind fo MyApp.App"? Maybe it is strange question, but what code you mean?

Comment: Expand `MyApp.xaml` in Visual Studio and open `MyApp.xaml.cs`.

Comment: He just pasted the `xaml.cs` code. Nothing suspicious...

Comment: I would say, your converter shouldn't be part of the resourcedictionary group, but rather of the resources

Comment: I'm confused (I don't do much WPF) but does the `Application` class have an `InitializeComponent` method?

Comment: I don't have a MyApp.xaml... I have only App.xaml

Comment: @DavidG No, it doesn't. But that code is generated by XAML (the extension is `g.cs`), not made by @BeataK

Comment: You partial 'code behind' class is actually a different class.  The code behind is `MyApp.MyApp.App` and your XAML is `MyApp.App`.  That would cause this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the order of the declarations ? Converters should be declared at first in ResourceDictionary.

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
 <local:MainMenuButtonVisibilityConverter x:Key="MainMenuButtonVisibilityConverter" />  <!-- withoot this line is fine-->
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that, somehow, adding the Converter directly to the `MergedDictionary` requires the class to implement `IComponentConnector` (and hence implement `InitializeComponent()`). Since `Application` doesn't implement `IComponentConnector`, you get this error.

Try moving the Converter definition around. Include it inside a ResourceDictionary or move it down to the Resources directly.

EDIT: Ok, seems like we all guessed the same at the same time :P